# Why does baidu crawl my site like crazy

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, baidu

When i'm checking my apache log I can see that baidu has been crawling my website 10 times a day for the last 2 weeks.

It's not that i care much about it but I'm really curious about why he's doing this.
It's a really small single page website with not much incoming links.

Is there any reason behind that?

```
220.181.108.169 [10/Mar/2012:10:41:29 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.197 [10/Mar/2012:11:02:02 +0100] "GET / ...robots.txt +(+http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm)"
123.125.71.100 [10/Mar/2012:11:33:15 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.167 [10/Mar/2012:11:33:52 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.116 [10/Mar/2012:12:24:48 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.172 [10/Mar/2012:12:25:05 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.111 [10/Mar/2012:13:33:22 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.167 [10/Mar/2012:13:34:03 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.168 [10/Mar/2012:14:12:05 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.107 [10/Mar/2012:14:23:41 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.176 [10/Mar/2012:14:23:58 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.94 [10/Mar/2012:15:25:59 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.183 [10/Mar/2012:15:26:21 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.92 [10/Mar/2012:17:45:55 +0100] "GET / ...robots.txt +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.71 [10/Mar/2012:17:45:57 +0100] "GET / ...robots.txt +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.79 [10/Mar/2012:17:46:04 +0100] "GET / ...robots.txt +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.103 [10/Mar/2012:17:47:32 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.179 [10/Mar/2012:17:48:37 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.108 [10/Mar/2012:18:37:21 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.185 [10/Mar/2012:18:38:13 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.96 [10/Mar/2012:19:25:50 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.169 [10/Mar/2012:19:25:59 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.101 [10/Mar/2012:20:25:51 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.176 [10/Mar/2012:20:26:09 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.105 [10/Mar/2012:21:33:38 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.178 [10/Mar/2012:21:34:15 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.170 [10/Mar/2012:21:57:39 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.98 [10/Mar/2012:22:26:13 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.175 [10/Mar/2012:22:26:33 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.104 [10/Mar/2012:23:34:09 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.169 [10/Mar/2012:23:34:48 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.171 [10/Mar/2012:23:52:22 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.168 [10/Mar/2012:23:52:22 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.110 [11/Mar/2012:00:33:52 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.184 [11/Mar/2012:00:34:27 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.103 [11/Mar/2012:02:37:21 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.177 [11/Mar/2012:02:37:58 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.97 [11/Mar/2012:03:34:30 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.172 [11/Mar/2012:03:35:07 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.107 [11/Mar/2012:04:35:33 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.178 [11/Mar/2012:04:36:16 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.115 [11/Mar/2012:05:34:31 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.187 [11/Mar/2012:05:35:12 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.97 [11/Mar/2012:06:24:17 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.181 [11/Mar/2012:06:24:32 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.112 [11/Mar/2012:07:40:27 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.187 [11/Mar/2012:07:41:17 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.95 [11/Mar/2012:08:29:42 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.175 [11/Mar/2012:08:30:07 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.105 [11/Mar/2012:09:35:23 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.184 [11/Mar/2012:09:36:05 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.106 [11/Mar/2012:10:39:32 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.165 [11/Mar/2012:10:40:11 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.171 [11/Mar/2012:11:23:57 +0100] "GET / ... +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

Comment: Do you receive any organic traffic from Baidu.com? If no I would block the spider if it's eating up your bandwidth like that.

Comment: Not sure about what you mean by organic traffic, but if you mean from users using baidu search engine, the answer is no i don't. It's not taking much bandwith or ressources. It's just that i'm curious why baidu is crawling it so much.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. If it's not taking up much bandwidth I wouldn't worry unless it continued. You could always email them.

" If you find any unreasonable access from Baiduspider, please inform us at spiderhelp@baidu.com"

Comment: I'd only block a search engine spider if you _never_ want to receive any search traffic from them, not just because you _currently_ don't receive any--especially considering that Baidu is the 3rd largest search engine in the world in terms of market share.

Comment: Baidu is **very** aggressive till it gets enough of your site indexed. There are scrapers out there that claim to be Baidu, I use http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/ to identify them and ban them when things get out of hand. Yandex can generate the same kind of traffic as well.

Comment: @FiascoLabs It would be great if you could share some of your experience with the Chinese search engines with us via the community wiki, we don't have much content about them.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - Hey! FYI, I cited your comment in a [new question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/50741/13067)

Comment: Aggressive? its outright ddos, 800 connections/sessions created in under 1 minute :( who are these idiots? so i blocked yet another chinese host last night *sigh*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't sound like something you should worry about too much, google crawls some of my sites in a similar way, but it could be a fake bot, so check out the links below...

The [Baidu Spider FAQ's](http://www.baidu.com/search/spider_english.html) (Chrome's built in translation) have this to say:-

> **4. Why Baiduspider crawls my site continuously?** In order to ensure the latest information is presented, Baiduspider crawls new pages or pages
>   frequently renewed at your site. Please check the log to see whether
>   the crawling from Baiduspider is reasonable.
>
> To avoid the excess crawling by spammers or other trouble makers who
>   pretend to be Baiduspider, you can check the log. *When you find any
>   abnormal crawling, please inform us at spiderhelp@baidu.com and
>   provide the log of Baiduspider.*

Baidu does offer it's own [version of webmaster tools](http://www.chinainternetwatch.com/1265/baidu-webmaster-tools/) (chrome's translation function will be needed when accessing the tools themselves) perhaps signing up for them might yield some answers. Google WMT offers limited ability to manage crawl rate, perhaps their tool offers some similar functionality.