# How to submit sitemap to Baidu?

Tags: sitemap, baidu

I've some pages in my site in Chinese but I don't understand Chinese (it's some GIS data).

Is there any way to submit sitemap to Baidu?

Comment: Use Google translate.

Answer (score 6):

http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/sitemap/index is the (sparse) documentation about **sitemaps** for Baidu. It only describes that it may help to submit your sitemap, and it shows a screenshot of their webmaster tool, listing several sitemaps and their status. However, it seems that they intend this feature only for "high quality" sites, on invitation basis.

Here is also a FAQ about sitemaps: http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=477. They say, for example, that

- they [follow the sitemaps.org standard](http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=477&id=1000436),
- they [support XML and TXT](http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=477&id=1000424),
- in the general case it should be [placed in the root](http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=477&id=1000428) as `sitemap.xml`, and
- a single sitemap must [not be larger](http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=477&id=1000429) than 10 MB or 50000 URLs.

So you’d need to [register an Baidu account](https://passport.baidu.com/v2/?reg), [login to their webmaster tool](http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/), [add and verify your site(s)](http://www.webnots.com/add-and-verify-site-in-baidu-webmaster-tools.html) and then … wait and hope that you are invited to upload your sitemap. I don’t know their process, but I wouldn’t assume that this will happen for your sites.

Alternatives?

http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/sitesubmit/index is their **site submission** tool, which even works anonymously. It’s probably intended to submit your website’s homepage only (e.g., `example.com`), but you also get a success message ("URL提交成功" = something like "URL successfully submitted") when entering the URL to your sitemap. However, this probably doesn’t mean that they’ll use your sitemap that way.

For **blogs**, they also offer a ping service http://ping.baidu.com/ping.html (XML RPC: `http://ping.baidu.com/ping/RPC2`) ([documentation](http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/tools/ping)). Entering your **feed** there is also possible.

And special cases: For **WordPress**, there seems to be an [official Baidu plugin](http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/dataplug/index) that pushes any new content to Baidu and allows them to show updates in real time. For [**Discuz!**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discuz!) forums, there is also a [Baidu sitemap submission plugin](http://addon.discuz.com/?@baidusubmit.plugin).

Comment: Unor my site is in Drupal though

Comment: https://passport.baidu.com/v2/?reg is giving forbidden error

Comment: @AgA: The link works for me. Alternative: On http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/, click at "立即注册" (below the login box).

Comment: @AgA: It doesn’t look like they offer something for Drupal, WordPress and  Discuz! seem to be exceptions. What is your actual use case? Just getting indexed by Baidu? Then submitting your site and, optionally, pinging them for new posts should be sufficient, shouldn’t it?

Comment: But my site is multilingual site and a few pages are in Chinese. Chinese page's aren't linked from the English home page though.

Answer (score 3):

Baidu has a Webmaster Tools application that is written in Chinese. But all is not lost. Here is a tutorial:

http://www.webnots.com/baidu-webmaster-tools.html

The tutorial is written in English and translates the options for you. I am not sure how up to date this is, but it does look complete otherwise and may be useful.

I do not see that Baidu reads the robots.txt file for a sitemap. But just in case, here is the format.

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_location.xml
```

Comment: See page 10 of the English guide in the link above: `Sitemap submission in Baidu webmaster tools is only on invitation basis. This means if your site is qualified for Sitemap submission then you will see an “Add Sitemap” button.`

Comment: Aw nuts! I missed that part. It seems that search engines should be more open these days because of all the competition. Not that Baidu ever returned a user or if they did, it was un-noticable.

Comment: It is a bit bewildering why they don't offer an English version of their Webmaster Tools, even though they crawl everywhere (and frequently).

Comment: Annoying as *strained poop* [expletive deleted] too! I had them blocked but had a change of heart a short while ago because they cover Japan. I know they have returned users, but it is hardly a blip on the screen. For all the spidering the do, there should be more. However, we have Bing and they are just as bad. I decided I should be more open especially with the aggressive anti-spider mechanism I have going. Almost too aggressive.

Comment: Check out [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50558/is-it-possible-to-slow-the-baiduspider-crawl-frequency) related question. We often see questions here asking how slow down their crawl rate - seems most feel the payoff isn't worth the resources consumed, but it's not that easy to do without an English translation. Perhaps that's intentional, or political...they surely have the means to provide one.

Comment: I agree. Baidu is sleazy in my book. I am not too worried about resources since I intentionally set traps for bad bots, hackers, and such. I study their behavior and report patterns to other researchers. I am writing some patents that I will make public. Some of this work is being used in new security tools already. This is why my site sucks. It has not been about publishing, it is about capturing data. Though I am working to make my site worth something eventually.

Comment: closetnoc I've already tried all available articles in internet. It does not work that way.

Comment: Have you tried the robots.txt file suggestion? It may take a while for Baidu to read the robots.txt file and possibly start using the sitemap file so patience may be needed. Baidu seems rather strange in how they do things.

Answer (score -2):

Baidu only accept submissions from china citizens.

**Update 2018: As of 2017, Baidu does not allow foreign nationals to have a webmaster's account :(**

source: https://www.codingbot.net/2017/03/submit-website-to-bing-google-baidu-yandex-duckduckgo.html

Comment: One line answers are generally not good enough here.  Can you add more about your experience with this matter, or link to references?