# How do you get your site discovered by users in China?

Tags: seo, google

I have a website in English and no translation available on the site. I would like to get the site indexed by Chinese search Engine. There are ways in which you can submit your site to Chinese search engines

My question is that if my site is in English and even though its gets submitted, will the crawler of Chinese search engine translate into its native language ? If users in China search for some terms in Chinese, will my site ever show up ?

Comment: You'd have to check how `baidu.com` accepts sitemaps/request

Comment: I am trying to understand behind the scenes working of crawler. Google offers search in native Indian languages to its users. I am sure users will not be submitting different site maps for each of the language.

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:google]. Does this mean your question is about [google.cn](http://www.google.cn/)?

Comment: Nope. Google has virtually no presence in China

Answer (score 1):

Check out [How to submit sitemap to Baidu?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59851/how-to-submit-sitemap-to-baidu/). It discusses how to submit a sitemap to Baidu. That may help some. But the up-shot of it all is that while it is easy to have Baidu spider your site, it is difficult to get Baidu to accept a submitted sitemap. You can add a sitemap specification to your robots.txt file which is in this answer. In case you do not know, Baidu is the largest search engine in Asia. So it may be worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the major ranking factors for search engines in China is that the server itself is hosted in China. Even if you can get your website index, ranking it is a different battle.

Users in China searching for terms in Chinese **may** end up on your website - because yes, it will be indexed in their native language - but I really doubt your website will rank high enough to receive enough impressions and clicks to make this worthwhile.

I've worked for several luxury CPG brands in North America, and routinely see Asian characters in our WMT/GA even though we do not have our sites translated into any Asian language.

Comment: Let me correct one thing. It used to be that search engines matched language, locale, and the physical location of a server and registration of a site for ranking relevance. Now, and precisely because China is *such* a *bad neighborhood*, the better Chinese based websites targeted to China have moved out of country. Ranking by neighborhood quality is the key and whether a site is in country can count against you. As for Chinese sites, it absolutely will. Do not confuse the ccTLD as having anything to do with the location of a site. Many foreign countries host their site in the US, UK, DE.