# Set bot crawl delay 10 seconds EXCEPT Googlebot?

Tags: search-engines, web-crawlers, robots.txt

Is it possible set the crawl delay for all bots to 10 seconds except Googlebot and Bing/Yahoo which can proceed at any pace?

I like being indexed by all these bots but with Yandex and Baidu it is just a bit overwhelming for my app which is very very database heavy.

Eventually I will cache stuff but right now i'm in beta. I do enjoy the traffic. Just need to slow these bots down a bit.

Comment: The `crawl-delay` in *robots.txt* is non-standard and most bots don't support it.   Yandex and Bing are about the only two that do support it.  Googlebot does not.

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to slow the Baiduspider crawl frequency?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50558/is-it-possible-to-slow-the-baiduspider-crawl-frequency)